# How can I debug remotely some code running on a Debian Virtual Machine from Eclipse debugger on host machine?

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, virtual-machine

I need to debug some C code which is running on a VM (which has a different architecture from host machine) from Eclipse debugger (which is on my host machine). Basically I need to monitor a variable to see which thread or function modifies it.

On VM I'm running 32-bit Debian 8, and on the host I have 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04. I compiled my code on both machine using gcc.

I tried configuring Eclipse remote debugger and I can connect to the VM, but I can't see any code inside Eclipse debugger (I can only see hex values which seem to be function's memory location), preventing me from using it.

Answer (score 0):

on the VM, run `dbg` or `ddd`

The above are both debuggers

Comment: By doing this I can debug on the VM. Unfortunately I necessarily have to debug remotely from the host...

Comment: I think I understand.   the gdb debugger. to be run remotely needs to have the `gdb server` running on the remote system